# angular dynamic model binding not working

Tags: angular

I have tried to dynamically bind the control using the angular but some reason it is not binding correctly. what I am missing here.

```
     <ng-container *ngFor='let ui of uiData'>
            <ng-container *ngIf="ui.position === 'left'">
                <div class="p-grid">
                    <div>
                        <label>{{ ui.label }}</label>
                    </div>
                    <div>
                        <input id="input" type="text" [(ngModel)]= "ui[model]">
                    </div>
                </div>
            </ng-container>
        </ng-container>



      <div>
            <button pButton type="button" (click)="SubmitData();" label="Save"></button>
        </div>
```

All I am trying to here is get the data user has entered on the fields when button clicks.

```
export class DynamicLoadComponent implements OnInit {
 uiData:any; 
 userData:UserDataModel  = null;

constructor() {

  this.uiData = [
    { label:"test1",position: "left", control: "textbox",model: "userData.child1.docNumber" },
    { label:"test1",position: "left", control: "textbox", model: "userData.child1.ws"},
    { label:"test1",position: "right", control: "textbox", model: "userData.child1.ns" },
    { label:"test1",position: "left", control: "textbox", model: "userData.child1.dueDate" },
    { label:"test1",position: "left", control: "textbox",model: "userData.child1.initDate" },
  ]

  }
  SubmitData(){
     console.log(this.userData);
   }

}
```

Model class looks like this

```
export class UserDataModel {
   child1: {
       docNumber: string;
      ws: number;
      ns: number;
      dueDate: string;
      initDate: string;
  }
}
```

Comment: Can you please add error description in console?

Comment: it looks to me to be an object and not an array, ie you should try `[(ngModel)]= "ui.model"`

Comment: or [(ngModel)]= "ui['model']"

Comment: It is not giving me an error. It is just not binding . On console I am just getting first element with empty value.(child1: {docNumber: "") . Rest element value is not even showing up on console

Comment: I have tried both [(ngModel)]= "ui.model" and [(ngModel)]= "ui['model']" but in both case it is not working. it just display key itself on UI

Comment: try [(ngModel)] = "userData[ui.model]"

Comment: can you please create a stackblitz to reproduce the issue

Comment: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-drgibg

Answer (score 1):

Your variable `uiDate` is an array of objects, therefore my guess is that you should address the item as  `[(ngModel)] = "ui.model"` instead of  `[(ngModel)] = "ui[model]"`

**EDIT**

just tried it out:

x.component.html:

```
<ng-container *ngFor='let ui of uiData'>
  <ng-container *ngIf="ui.position === 'left'">
      <div class="p-grid">
          <div>
              <label>{{ ui.label }}</label>
          </div>
          <div>
              <input id="input" type="text" [(ngModel)]= "ui.model">
          </div>
      </div>
  </ng-container>
</ng-container>



<div>
  <button pButton type="button" (click)="SubmitData();" label="Save"></button>
</div>
```

x.component.ts :

```
uiData:any; 
  userData:any  = null;

 constructor() {

   this.uiData = [
     { label:"test1",position: "left", control: "textbox",model: "userData.child1.docNumber" },
     { label:"test1",position: "left", control: "textbox", model: "userData.child1.wi"},
     { label:"test1",position: "right", control: "textbox", model: "userData.child1.nri" },
     { label:"test1",position: "left", control: "textbox", model: "userData.child1.dueDate" },
     { label:"test1",position: "left", control: "textbox",model: "userData.child1.initDate" },
   ]

   }
   SubmitData(){
      console.log(this.userData);
    }
```

results in:

[image]

Comment: I have tried both [(ngModel)]= "ui.model" and [(ngModel)]= "ui['model']" but in both case it is not working. it just display key itself on UI

Comment: @LilRazi `uiData:any; `  and `this.uiDate = [`  do not match... is this a typo?

Comment: we do not want to display userData.child1.docNum on textbox right? It should be bind data i.e. whatever user enter on the field and that value should bind to It. Like binddata for first textbox should bind to userData.child1.docNum .

Comment: yes, but instead I want to grab the user data and bind to respective field not to display the key itself on textbox

Answer (score 0):

You have to instanciate UserDataModel and set  [(ngModel)] = "userData[ui.model]"